# When is the proof-techniques tag appropriate?

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm not sure which questions fall under the tag [proof-techniques](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proof-techniques). In particular, are questions which essentially ask for a specific proof of a statement appropriate? The current tag description:

> Questions about methods and techniques for proving theorems.

doesn't seem to exclude this case, while maybe it should.

Perhaps a description such as

> Questions about *general* methods and techniques for proving *multiple* theorems. When asking about the proof of a single statement, use [some-tag-specifically-for-proofs?] instead.

would be better.

Should the tag excerpt be changed? Should some tag specifically for proofs be created? (We already have the [correctness-proof](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/correctness-proof) tag, but that deals specifically with the correctness of *algorithms*, while proofs of other statements or even other properties of algorithms can also be on-topic). Any further thoughts?

Comment: I think you understood the intent of the tag well. Your proposed tag description is indeed better; I'd put something like "use tags relating to what the proof is about instead". That's what we've been doing, anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I've gone ahead an suggested a new tag description to [proof-techniques](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proof-techniques):

> Questions about general methods and techniques for proving multiple theorems. When asking about the proof of a single statement, use tags relating to what the proof is about instead.

, which got accepted. I feel the tag intent is more clearly represented now.

Comment: I think so, too, thanks!